# How are permissions in linux implemented?

Tags: linux, files, permissions, acl

It is in my knowledge that Linux implements a DAC-based model for file access control, however I recently came across the fact that [ACL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) have to [manually be enabled](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) in Linux.

My question is: How does the default file access control method work? Does it bind its permissions to every file or does Linux use a capability-based model for file access control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setfacl` are for the fancy POSIX [`acl(5)`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl), which are an optional thing you can use on top of the traditional and default unix access permissions of user, group, other and the read, write, execute (and various sticky) bits. The optional `acl(5)` stuff shows up with a `+` in a directory listing:

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 user staff 4096 Sep  8 18:25 dir
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 user staff 4096 Sep  8 18:25 facldir
```

As for how the default permissions work, Stevens in "APUE" covers that in detail.

Comment: There is nothing called "POSIX ACLs". There was an ACL proposal from 1993, mainly issued by Sun but the related draft was withdrawn in 1997 because the users did not like that ACL proposal.

Comment: Complain to the linux man page folks: "This manual page describes POSIX Access Control Lists...

Comment: The problem is that since more than 10 years, there is a real ACL standard. This standard ACL concept was (bit-identically) derived from NTFS and is part of the NFSv4 standard. Linux started to implement the withdrawn ACL proposal in 2001 - 4 years after it was withdrawn.